# How does Git Eclipse plugin know revisions from before I installed the plugin?

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, egit, jgit

WHOA ...  So I just installed the Git Eclipse plugin and kicked some tires.  Made a change and checked it in and all.   But I noticed that revision history on a file included changes I made yesterday **BEFORE I HAD INSTALLED GIT**.  How does Eclipse Git know of these changes?  They are indeed accurate.  Does the basic Eclipse keep a cache of recent file changes and then they get ported into Git or Git reads them somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse also has the concept of a "Local History", which is independent of EGit. See [this chapter in the Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-55.htm).